# Using Git, How do I see a file at a specific revision?

Tags: git

Using git, how do I see a file at a specific revision without checking it out?

I've asked this question a thousand times and can never remember the obscure way git goes about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
git show rev:path
```

*rev* is a revision specified according to the rules in `git-rev-parse(1)`; e.g. a commit hash or a brach name.

*path* is the path to a file; relative to the repository root by default, but relative to current directory if prefixed with `./`.

Comment: What and by `commit` you mean the commit code? And by `file` the file's name? Or its path? Can you expand your answer a little?